# sql query exist with conditional

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT sg.*
FROM   stokgudang sg
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT kd.*
                  FROM   killer_dry kd                                 
                  WHERE  kd.id_output_breakdown = sg.id_output_breakdown)
  AND sg.after_airdry= 'True' OR sg.status_airdry = 'True'
```

What I want is don't show id_output_breakdown that already in the killer_dry, only show when it's not yet in the killer_dry that sg.after_aidry = true OR status_airdry = True

But when it's already in the killer_dry, id_output_breakdown is still on the list, why?

Comment: AND (sg.after_airdry= 'True' OR sg.status_airdry = 'True') ?

Comment: wow, thanks man, can you explain how "( )" logic on SQL base on my query?

Comment: Without them the AND is evaluated before the OR, which is not what you want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give this a try:

```
SELECT  sg.*
FROM    stokgudang sg
        LEFT JOIN killer_dry kd ON 
            kd.id_output_breakdown = sg.id_output_breakdown
            AND (sg.after_airdry= 'True' OR sg.status_airdry = 'True')
WHERE   kd.id_output_breakdown IS NULL
```

btw: avoid using "*" in your select list, only select the columns you need, even if i need all columns i specify them by name. So you avoid bad suprises when you add/delete a column in the table!

Comment: it also works like a charm, sure mate, I'm still new to PHP and MySql
can you tell me what the last line is?

Comment: @AlexYamin Try excluding the last line, but including kd.* in the SELECT

Comment: if you want to do something like "all records from table a which are not in table b" you can use EXISTS clause or you can do i it with a simple left join. All you need to do is:  `select .. from table a left join table b on a.id = b.id where b.id is null`

Comment: @Strawberry well, if I exclude the last line and add kd.*, the data is show hahaha

Comment: @AlexYamin So now you know what the last line does.

Comment: @AlexYamin if you do what @Strawberry says you can see, which lines will be eliminated with the last `line WHERE kd.id_output_breakdown IS NULL`   this was just an advice to show you how my statement works...

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this, although I suspect that there are better solutions than that correlated subquery:

```
SELECT sg.*
  FROM stokgudang sg
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT kd.*
                     FROM killer_dry kd                                 
                    WHERE  kd.id_output_breakdown = sg.id_output_breakdown)
   AND 'True' IN(sg.after_airdry,sg.status_airdry)
```